# Maximum of the finite Blaschke Products

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

Given any finite Blaschke Product $B$ how to characterize the points where $|B|$ attains its maximum. Since $B$ is continuous in the closed disc, existence of such points is guaranteed. Also, can we confer any topological properties, such as connectedness, of the set $M_B$, where

$M_B:=\{x\in \bar{D}:~|B(x)|=\max_{z\in \bar{D}} |B (z)| \}.$

I am a novice in complex analysis and a detailed answer would be of very much help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that any Blaschke product maps the unit circle into itself?

Comment: Yes! Blaschke Product maps unit circle onto itself@Mindlack

Comment: So why isn’t $M_B$ just the unit circle, by the maximum modulus principle?

Comment: Indeed! Thank you@Mindlack